# Pivot-Page SelectionChanged doesn't react

Tags: c#, windows-phone, pivot

I wrote a selectionChanged event handler into my MainPage.cs, but it does not react when I change the pivot page:

```
 private void MainPage_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Pivot selection changed");
    switch (((Pivot)sender).SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            Debug.WriteLine("LoginAppBar launched");
            ApplicationBar = ((ApplicationBar)Application.Current.Resources["LoginAppBar"]);
            break;

        case 1:
            Debug.WriteLine("DefaultAppBar launched");
            ApplicationBar = ((ApplicationBar)Application.Current.Resources["AppBar"]);
            break;

        case 2:
            Debug.WriteLine("DefaultAppBar launched");
            ApplicationBar = ((ApplicationBar)Application.Current.Resources["AppBar"]);
            break;
    }
}
```

Why does this event handler not work? Is it the name of the method? I tried to change the method-header to private void `myNameSpaceHere_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)`

but it still doesn't catch the event.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Allright, got it. I didn't edit the XAML:

```
 <controls:Pivot Title="APP"
                        x:Name="Pivot"
                        SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged"
                        Foreground="#FF72BCE6"
                        BorderThickness="2">
```

I had to add an SelectionChanged attribute.